# Set of all non units of a ring is maximal ideal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Prove or disprove:
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and let $I$ be the set of all the non units of $R$. Then $I$ is a maximal ideal of $R$.

The result is not true. Take $R=\mathbb Z$ then $2,3\in I$ but $2-3=-1\notin I$ .  Thus $I$ is not even an ideal.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. This condition that the non-units form an ideal is one of the equivalent definitions of $R$ being a local ring so any non-local ring is a counterexample.